# How to setup a DNS with a socat based vpn?

Tags: dns, vpn, tunneling, socat

Since socat has the functionality of creating tunnel interfaces and route traffic over UDP,  I believe a VPN can be created using this feature.

Server side setup:

- `sudo socat -d -d TUN:10.0.0.1/24,up  UDP-LISTEN:<PORT>,reuseaddr,fork`
- `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT`
- `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Client side setup:

- `sudo socat UDP:<PUBLIC-HOST>:<PORT>  TUN:10.0.0.2/24,up`
- `sudo ip route replace default 10.0.0.1`
- `ip route add <PUBLIC-HOST> via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0`

As far as I can tell this works fine as I can ping the server on `10.0.0.1` but when trying to ping `google.com` it fails with

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Can anyone point out what is missing from this configuration/setup?